# Mistake in example code given in the MATLAB documentation for training multiple NN

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, feed-forward

In [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/improve-neural-network-generalization-and-avoid-overfitting.html#bss4gz0-38) we are training 10 different neural networks, each initialized with different weights and biases. `net` is the variable for constructing the neural networks, `x1` is the training dataset, `t1` is the known labels used in training, `x2` is the test dataset and `t2` is the test label. Each neural network is stored in a cell variable `NN{}`.

After training, the evaluation is done using the test set `t2` and `x2`, However, the mse calculation is done using `mse(net, t2, y2)`I think the correct statement should have been `mse(NN{i}, t2, y2)` since `NN{}` is the trained model and not `net` which is just a structure. Below is the code given in the link.

Should the function call be `mse(NN{i}, t2, y2)` instead of `mse(net, t2, y2)`?

```
net = feedforwardnet(10);
numNN = 10;
NN = cell(1, numNN);
perfs = zeros(1, numNN);
for i = 1:numNN
  fprintf('Training %d/%d\n', i, numNN);
  NN{i} = train(net, x1, t1);
  y2 = NN{i}(x2);
  perfs(i) = mse(net, t2, y2);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `mse` is a network performance function. It measures the network’s
>   performance according to the mean of squared errors.
>
> `perf = mse(net,t,y,ew)` takes these arguments:
>
> - `net` Neural network
> - `t` Matrix or cell array of targets
> - `y` Matrix or cell array of outputs
> - `ew` Error weights (optional)

As per the [documentation of `mse`](https://mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/mse.html). So the first parameter *should* be a structure of the `neural network` type, with `NN{i}` being contained in `y2` in that example, thus the matrix of outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the example code in Matlab documentation is correct? The purpose of this code is to select the NN which gives the lowest MSE. It is quite unclear which variable should I use as the final NN model? The way I would select the model is after the loop ends,`[minErr indx] = min(perfs); bestModel = NN{indx};` If `net` is the model then there is no array of nets to select from.  Can you please tell me which variable is the model?